# Baixar várias imagens de uma vez de um site em php

Tags: php, c, download, image

Seguinte, tem um site no qual preciso baixar várias imagens,
consigo ter accesso a imagem da seguinte forma:
`url.com/get_img.php?user=VARIÁVEL`

onde **variável** é substituida por um inteiro e o mesmo me retorna uma imagem em *PNG*.

Preciso de uma ajuda para saber como posso criar um código para automatizar o trabalho (uma luz para saber por onde começar, dicas e etc)

Desde já, agradeço a atenção, Obrigado.

*Obs:* Sou um bom programador C, mas entendo pouco de outras linguagens, e sei que terei de aprender o básico, pois não sei se dará para fazer em C.

Answer (score 2):

Você pode fazer utilizando [**file_get_contents**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-get-contents.php) e [**file_put_contents**](http://php.net/manual/pt_BR/function.file-put-contents.php) ou [**curl**](http://br.php.net/manual/pt_BR/book.curl.php).

O `file_get_contents` pode ler um arquivo local ou externo. É especialmente indicado para casos mais simples. Apesar de te a liberdade para passar alguns cabeçalhos, não chega a ser tão completo quanto o `cURL`, mas é uma boa opção.

Você pode utiliza-lo da seguinte forma.

```
<?php

/* ID's da imagem */
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

foreach($ids as $id) {
    /* Acessa, baixa e armazena o arquivo na variável $content */
    $content = file_get_contents("https://url.com/get_img.php?user={$id}");

    /* Escreve o conteúdo da variável $content em 1.png, 2.png, 3.png ... */
    file_put_contents("{$id}.png", $content);
}
```

Com o `cURL` você consegue trabalhar melhor com *Cookies*, *Headers*, *Follow Location*, *Authentication* etc. É uma ferramenta completa para requisições. Irei usar como exemplo o básico.

```
<?php

/* ID's da imagem */
$ids = [1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10];

foreach($ids as $id) {

    /* Cria um novo arquivo e caso o arquivo exista, substitui */
    $file = fopen("{$id}.png", "w+");

    /* Cria uma nova instância do cURL */
    $curl = curl_init();

    curl_setopt_array($curl, [
        /* Define a URL */
        CURLOPT_URL            => "https://url.com/get_img.php?user={$id}",

        /* Informa que você quer receber o retorno */
        CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,

        /* Define o "resource" do arquivo (Onde o arquivo deve ser salvo) */
        CURLOPT_FILE           => $file,

        /* Header Referer (Opcional) */
        CURLOPT_REFERER        => "https://url.com",

        /* Desabilita a verificação do SSL */
        CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER => false
    ]);

    /* Envia a requisição e fecha as conexões em seguida */
    curl_exec($curl);
    curl_close($curl);
    fclose($file);
}
```

*Obs.:* Dá para fazer muitas coisas com *C*, inclusive isso. Lembre-se que o 
 *PHP* é desenvolvido com *C*.

Answer (score 0):

Ao que entendi o site não é seu, então você está tentando obter todas as imagens com um único método de download, caso contrário você acessaria o FTP diretamente e as baixaria.

Vamos tentar resolver por `JAVASCRIPT` pelo navegador, então você irá criar um HTML por qualquer editor de texto que será aberto diretamente pelo seu navegador sem precisar rodar de um servidor:

```js
function loadImgs(){
  /*--- Dados do formulário ---*/
  var dataform = document.forms[0] || document.forms['dados'];
  var t = dataform.imgtotal.value;
  var url = dataform.url.value;
  var ext = dataform.ext.value;
  dataform.buscar.disabled = true;
  /*--- Gerar IMGS ---*/
  var div = document.getElementById('dl_imgs') || document.dl_imgs;
  div.innerHTML = "";
  for(i=0;i<t;i++){
    div.innerHTML += '<img src="'+url+""+i+''+ext+'" />';
  }
}
```

```css
img{
  margin:10px;
  border-style: double;
  background-color:#f0f0f0;
  width: 50px;
  height: 50px;
}

#dl_imgs{
  margin:10px;
  background-color: #0fffff;
}
```

```html
<form name="dados">
URL (Com HTTP e parametros): <input value="" name="url" type="text" /><br />
Aumente até o número estimativo: <input value="100" name="imgtotal" type="number" /><br />
Preencha a extensão com ponto ou deixe vazio: <input value=".png" name="ext" type="text" /><br />
<input value="Buscar" name="buscar" type="button" onclick="loadImgs()" />
</form>
<div id="dl_imgs"></div>
```

Após carregar todas as imagens use o comando `Ctrl`+`S` para salvar uma cópia da página, ele salvará todas as imagens carregadas numa pasta com o nome do arquivo que você definir:
*site_arquivos*